# Bot mention only

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The code that I provided below is 100% working. However, if there's a message before and after the mention it still sends the message. I'm not quite sure how the bot will ignore that. This request might be too much but if you could fix the code I would really appreciate it.

```
   client.on('message', async message => {
      let a = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
      if (message.author.bot) return;
      if (!message.guild) return;

      if(message.content.match(`${client.user.id}`))
         message.channel.send(`My prefix is this server is: \`${a}\``);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're telling the bot to send the prefix if the message **includes** its mention (or its id), while what you really want is to see whether it **starts with** with the mention.
To do that, you could either check it using `.startsWith()` and then build a mention, so that it would work like your prefix; the easier way is to see whether the **first "word"** of the message includes your ID.
You also want to make sure that the first "word" is actually the only one.

```js
if (message.content.split(' ')[0].includes(client.user.id) && message.content.split(' ').length == 1) {
  // The message was "@YourBot", you can do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I tried the code that you provided. However, it's still doing the same thing. Still sending the message.

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood the question: you want the bot to reply to messages like "@Bot do something" but not to "bla bla bla @Bot bla bla bla", is that right? Because if that's the case I really don't see how that could happen with my code. What kind of message are you sending?

Comment: I’m just trying to mention the bot itself. No other messages, just the mention.

Comment: Oh, ok. Let me know if I got it: you only want the message to be sent when someone send a message that looks like "@Bot", but not when it has any other text. Is that correct?

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet. However, you're correct. I just want the bot mention and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however, it's still doing the same thing: https://imgur.com/a/mrRZ3Ux

Comment: That's impossible since there was an error in my code (I used `args`, but forgot that you hadn't defined it). That means you haven't completely deleted the previous code

Comment: Happy to hear that :)